# Reinstantiating deployed contract

Tags: abi

Looked at multiple answer for this question but they seem to be out of date.

I committed a contract to the testnet chain, closed my geth console and upon starting the console again would like to redeploy contract.  I know that I have to load the .abi file in and then instantiate a new local contract, but I keep getting an error.  Below is code:

```
loadScript(Token.abi); \\ script assigning abi string to variable 'Token'
var myContract = eth.contract(Token); \\ works fine
var myContractInstance = myContract.at('0x808eca33fef859f9aa54c24780962b0519e274b8') \\ here the error is returned
```

The error given is

```
TypeError: 'filter is not a function'
```

I don't see the .at() function anywhere in the documentation so I assume it is deprecated?  Any ideas?

EDIT:

I did find the .at() function on the api wiki, but for some reason it does not seem to work.

Comment: You have to do something like `eth.contract(JSON.parse(abiDefinition))`. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16798/web3-uncaught-typeerror-contract-abi-filter-is-not-a-function for more details.

Comment: That is essentially what is in the script Token.abi, I modified that file to include javacsript commands to assign the array.  I can create a contract using eth.contract() just fine, but when using eth.contract().at() I run into this error @Ismael

Comment: But from your question you were doing `eth.contract(Token)` instead of `eth.contract(Token.abi)`. Just the error doesn't trigger immediately, only when the it is used in `myContract.at('xxxx')`.